# Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) when installing factoextra

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm trying to install the "factoextra" package using a local source tar ball on Windows.  I can install other packages in the same way with no problem.  However, when installing "factoextra", I get an error relating to S3methods.

I have tried using local windows binaries, installing the latest Rtools and made sure I have all the dependencies installed.  I have also tried to use archived versions of the package.

```
install.packages('D:\\R_Packages\\Packages\\factoextra_1.0.5.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")

* installing *source* package 'factoextra' ...
** package 'factoextra' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'factoextra'
* removing 'D:/R-3.5.2/library/factoextra'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘D:/R_Packages/Packages/factoextra_1.0.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I really just need this package to install.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this thread: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-in-rbind-info-getNamespaceInfo-env-quot-S3methods-quot-td4755490.html, which leads me to how I solved a similar issue on my machine.

I found that a broken version of the package was installed on my system and had to be removed manually before I could install a clean version.

Find if and where `factoextra` is installed (it might be on your system, just outdated or broken):

```
find.package("factoextra")
```

If it's there already (just broken), you can try to remove it with:

```
remove.packages("factoextra")
```

If `remove.packages()` fails even though `find.packages()` says the package is there, use the path returned by `find.packages()` to use your OS' file system to find and delete the package - just be careful only to delete stuff you know is broken.

Once the old, broken package is removed, use `install.packages("factoextra")` and it should work.

I had several packages that were broken in this way. If that's the case for you, you can identify which packages to remove and install this way by using something like:

```
allPackages <- installed.packages()[, 1]
findBrokenPackages <- function(packages) {
    for (p in packages) {
        tryCatch(ncol(asNamespace(p)$.__NAMESPACE__.$S3methods),
                 error = function(e) print(c(p, e)))
    }
}
findBrokenPackages(allPackages)
```

This will print out any packages that have the same issue. I would suggest removing all broken packages before trying to use `install.packages()` again.

Comment: The code to find broken packages was a great solution.  It appeared that some dependencies were broken.  Once I reinstalled them (fixed them) then I could install factoextra with no errors.  Thank you!

Comment: I am finding that all packages installed by local binaries [e.g install.packages('D:\\R_Packages\\Packages\\gmp_0.5-13.5.zip', repos = NULL, type="win.binary") ] leads to the same error.  The package installs with no error, but gives the S3methods error on loading via library(gmp).  Any tips as to why installing from binaries has suddenly stopped working for me?

Comment: @LisaClark Did you upgrade R recently? And does the above solution work to fix the binary installs after this happens? If so, I'm afraid it might just be growing pains with the upgrade. If you can't install some package at all, even after trying above, you might need to start another question with more details.

Comment: Sadly, no recent upgrade, but something must have changed.  I will keep persevering.  Thanks for your help!