# How to import library "EBImage" into RStudio environment?

Tags: r

I am trying to use library **"EBImage"**. While loading the package into Rstudio console, it throwing error "package or namespace load failed for ‘EBImage’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")): number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)".
I am not able to fix this problem by looking at information given in post :
"[Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) when installing factoextra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925357/error-in-rbindinfo-getnamespaceinfoenv-s3methods-when-installing-factoex)" on stackoverflow.

I just downloaded **R 3.6.0.**
Earlier I was using **R 3.5 version**
After upgrading to **R 3.6.0** getting such an error.

```
library("EBImage")
```

just wanted to load **"EBImage"** into the R environment.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first install the `EBImage` using the following code

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("EBImage")
```

Then you can load `EBImage` using `library()` function like

```
library("EBImage")
```