# Errors Installing and Calling R Packages

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently got a new work computer where they reinstalled RStudio on it. The RStudio version was the same as the one I had on my previous computer which worked perfectly.

On my previous computer I would install and call the packages from a local folder by simply typing this code `.libPaths("C:/R/Lib")`. This worked perfectly for me, but now with my new computer I get an error whenever I try to call these libraries. The error message I'm getting is:

```
> .libPaths("C:/R/Lib")
> 
Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(file, skipNul = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/R/Lib/abd/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In readLines(file, skipNul = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/R/Lib/acepack/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

> library(kableExtra)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘kableExtra’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
 number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘kableExtra’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue is greatly appreciatted!

Comment: what version of R are you using? did you reinstall the packages on your new computer ?

Comment: 1.3.1056 but I think the version shouldnt be an issue since I used the same version on my old computer the other day and everything worked fine. I did reinstall most of the packages.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55939741/5783745

Comment: 1.3.1056 is your RStudio version, which is an IDE not the actual R programming language. If you run sessionInfo(),  the first line will tell you the R version. Probably will be in the 3.x or 4.x range.

Comment: It's the R version that matters for compatibility of installed packages.

Comment: sorry @Marcus that was stupid of me. The R version is 3.5.1

Comment: Maybe worth trying to reinstall trouble packages from source since you are a minor release behind the version packages were built under. I'm not sure all the implications, but scanning the NEWS for the 3.6 releases there is mention of changes to S3method registration and packaging compiling for Windows.